# SQL query select between two dates error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am in need of your help as I am struggling with a query in SQL. This query is not giving exact result that I want. I need to pull out all the dates between two dates.

I tried two queries:

```
SELECT a.MemberID,CONVERT(varchar(12), b.BirthDate, 101) AS BirthDate
FROM Members_Hired AS a
    INNER JOIN Members AS b
        ON a.ReferenceID = b.RecordID
WHERE (CONVERT(varchar(12), b.BirthDate, 101) >= '02/01/2013'
    and CONVERT(varchar(12), b.BirthDate, 101) <= '02/27/2013')
```

and

```
SELECT a.MemberID,CONVERT(varchar(12), b.BirthDate, 101) AS BirthDate
FROM Members_Hired AS a
    INNER JOIN Members AS b
        ON a.ReferenceID = b.RecordID
WHERE (CONVERT(varchar(12), b.BirthDate, 101) BETWEEN '02/01/2013' and '02/27/2013')
```

This gives results with the date `'02/05/1990'`, `'02/17/1990'` also. It considers only month and date, not the year exactly.

Comment: Won't 1990 be the year?

Comment: If you are comparing dates, you have to reverse it so yyyy comes first, then mm, then dd.  If birthdate is a date field, you could potentially convert it using to_char(b.birthdate,'yyyy-mm-dd') - that would be Oracle syntax though which is why I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer

Comment: What type is b.BirthDate? Is it date, datetime, or something else?

Comment: While the answers given are right about using date/time types for comparisons, they all miss one thing - [they shouldn't be using BETWEEN (especially on SQL Server)](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Anything else is the wrong way to think of time...

Answer (score 8):

You should compare dates not varchar values. Change your where clause as below. Also note that I am using ISO format (yyyymmdd) for string dates before converting to make sure it works in any culture.

```
b.birthdate between convert(date,'20130201' ) and 
                  convert(date, '20130227')
```

Comment: I'd give another upvote if I could for using a dateformat that is not culture specific too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are comparing the string instead of date time, so the results have the records '02/25' & '02/17'.

Comment: remove all "CONVERT" from your "where" clause.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your birthdate field is a `DateTime` type you need to convert you inputs to the same type.

Did you try?

```
WHERE (b.BirthDate BETWEEN Cast('02/01/2013' As DateTime) and Cast('02/27/2013' As DateTime))
```

Comment: Dangerous. What if I'm in the UK? Now it's looking for January 2 instead of February 1.

Comment: The dates where the OP's dates. Am I incorrect that the `Cast` is culture respective? If the OP was in the UK, the date parameters would be different not the statement (01/02/2013 and 27/02/2013)? Just asking

Comment: My point is that encouraging regional formats (even if the OP introduced them) is a bad idea. The reason? The next reader of your answer might not have the same requirements as the OP, and may be looking for 2/1 -> 2/8, so the "obvious" format in your answer might be totally missed. Please read https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries and https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common